# « Revoir », « changer », « modifier » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

La signalisation routière et le marquage au sol sur la rue du Roi

> …ont été revus. Cela s’inscrit sans nul doute dans le nouveau projet urbain visant à rendre la ville plus sécuritaire.

> …ont été changés. Cela s’inscrit sans nul doute dans le nouveau projet urbain visant à rendre la ville plus sécuritaire.

> …sont changés. Cela s’inscrit sans nul doute dans le nouveau projet urbain visant à rendre la ville plus sécuritaire.

> …ont été modifiés. Cela s’inscrit sans nul doute dans le nouveau projet urbain visant à rendre la ville plus sécuritaire.

> …sont modifiés. Cela s’inscrit sans nul doute dans le nouveau projet urbain visant à rendre la ville plus sécuritaire.

Autre tournure d’un autre style.

> Des changements ont été apportés à la signalisation routière et au marquage au sol rue du Roi. Cela doit sans nul doute s’inscrire dans le nouveau projet urbain visant à rendre la ville plus sécuritaire.

N’hésitez pas à m’offrir une version refondue.

Comment: Je dirais que *revu* n'implique pas forcement de changement - ça peut signifier que quelqu'un donné un regard critique ou simplement qu'on a ramené ce sujet à la réunion. *Modification*, a mon avis, est un petit *changement* - le choix entre les deux depend du contexte. Je ne suis pas sur sur la nuance d'utilisation du passif present vs. le passif passé.

Comment: *… ont été amendés*, selon ce contexte

Comment: @Pretzel je pense qu'il manque une indication d'intention pour que cette question soit un peu moins basée sur l'opinion et un peu plus factuelle. Que veut-on dire précisément ? Veut-on insister sur l'aspect "rectification" ? Sur le fait qu'il y a un changement quel qu'il soit ? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le sens approprié du  verbe « revoir » se trouve dans le TLFi au « **B. 1. b) α)** » de son entrée (copie ci-dessous). Le sens général, qui doit  être applicable (**1.**, *Reprendre pour examiner*), ne permet pas d'affirmer si  des modifications ont  été faites.  De même, le sens spécifique (**b) α)**) ne laisse supposer à propos de quelconques modifications que leur éventualité. « Revoir » ne peut donc pas être  compris comme un quasisynonyme  de « changer » ou « modifier ». Il est alors question de savoir ce que l'on veut exprimer.  Comme les tournures  sans ambigüité possible quant à l'existence d'un changement (changer, modifier) laissent supposer qu'il y en a eu un ou qu'il y en a un de prévu, cette première phrase ne convient pas.  S'il  ne  s'agit que de changements partiels il vaut mieux utiliser « modifier » ; si le système a été entièrement repensé, alors l'utilisation de « changer »  traduit plus précisément la réalité.

Le passé composé sert à exprimer des actions  terminées,  donc il convient pour des changements ou des modifications qui viennent d'être terminés. Cependant, il existe une ambigüité non résoluble : il n'est pas clair dans ce type de contexte (décision et action correspondante) si on parle d' une décision de changement ou de l'action elle-même. Le passif n'est pas moins vague : les deux possibilités d'une action accomplie et d'une  action  à venir restent ouvertes et le contexte permet de décider mais pas toujours, quelle  option est la bonne. (Le passé récent n'est d'aucune utilité pour remédier à ce problème (« *viennent d'être modifiés* »), il faut changer la phrase.)

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/revoir))
> **B.** −
> **1.** **Reprendre pour examiner**.
> **a) Reconsidérer des éléments, une période du passé pour les soumettre à une analyse.** Synon. passer en revue.
>
> - On n'est pas mûr, à vingt-cinq ans, pour revoir et annoter sa vie (A. Daudet, Trente ans Paris, 1888, p. 75).
> - Pierre passa tout ce temps-là à chercher, creuser, revoir des détails, évoquer Paul et sa mère, se rappeler leur vie, leur intimité, ressusciter des incidents et crisper les poings, et pleurer tout seul de fureur et de désespoir (Van der Meersch, Invas. 14, 1935, p. 265).
>
> **b)**
> **α) Voir de nouveau d'un œil critique, examiner pour relever les imperfections et éventuellement modifier, corriger, amender.**
> − **[Le compl. désigne une chose concr.]**
>
> - [Landolfi (Carlo Ferdinando). Luthier italien, 1735-1775] marquait ainsi les instruments qu'il avait revus : Revisto da Carlo Ferdinando Landolfi l'Anno 1741 (Grillet, Ancêtres violon, t. 2, 1901, p. 203).
>
> **− En partic., dans le domaine de l'écriture.** Synon. relire, réviser.  Revoir un texte, des épreuves.
>
> - Le matin, de sept à onze heures, je revois mon manuscrit, car j'y travaille jusqu'à la dernière minute, et encore çà et là des choses m'échappent (Hugo, Corresp., 1862, p. 379).
> - L'écrivain a le temps de revoir minutieusement ce qu'il a écrit, de corriger, de modifier, de polir, de fignoler ses phrases, de soigner son style. Tout cela est refusé au journaliste (Coston, A.B.C. journ., 1952, p. 93).
>   *Au passif*.
> - Il est aisé de deviner, à certains détails, (...) [que le récit] a été revu, sinon rédigé, à l'état-major (Bordeaux, Fort de Vaux, 1916, p. 273).
>
> **− [Le compl. désigne une chose abstr.]** Revoir des conclusions, des hypothèses ; revoir une politique.
>
> - Ici comme dans beaucoup d'autres domaines, nous sommes obligés de modifier nos attitudes et de revoir nos principes (Univ. écon. et soc., 1960, p. 62-12).
> - Bien avant l'apparition du pur-sang, l'élimination de la lourde chevalerie en armure et l'entrée en service de montures plus légères, tel le cheval arabe, avaient conduit à revoir et à perfectionner les règles de l'équitation (P. Rousseau, Hist. transp., 1961, p. 166).
>
> **β) Expr. Revu et corrigé**. Qui a été remanié ; dont la forme, le contenu, les caractéristiques ont été modifiés et généralement améliorés.
>
> - Depuis la fameuse lettre du 31 mai 1897, où le faussaire Henry adressait à son supérieur le colonel Picquart une lettre de menaces et d'outrages préalablement revue et corrigée par Boisdeffre et par Gonse, tous les fabricateurs de faux n'ont cessé de jurer que Picquart avait fabriqué le « petit bleu » (Clemenceau, Vers réparation, 1899, p. 214).
>   *En empl. adj.*
> - L'art de Joseph Bernard repose sur la stylisation. Alliage de feinte gaucherie et de préciosité, cet art représente un aimable composé du maniérisme gothique du XV<sup>e</sup> siècle et d'un hellénisme revu et corrigé (Arts et litt., 1936, p. 18-2).
>
> **♦ Var.**
>
> - Les Sardes inquiètent la division Sérurier par des reconnaissances offensives. (...) [Bonaparte] renforce cette division de la brigade Rusca poussée à Bardinetto. Le système d'avant-postes de Schérer est soigneusement *revu et amélioré* (Foch, Princ. guerre, 1911, p. 70).
> - M. le Dr Seiffert a donné [des œuvres d'orgue de Buxtehude] (...) une nouvelle édition *revue et complétée* (Pirro, J.-S. Bach, 1919, p. 32).
> - Étienne Gilson vient de publier (...) une seconde édition, entièrement *revue et augmentée* (L. Febvre, Gilson et la philos. du XIV<sup>e</sup> s., [1946] ds Combats, 1953, p. 284).

Les deux verbes peuvent être combinés selon l'usage spécifié dans l'entrée de « revoir » (**Expr., Var.**).

- La signalisation routière et le marquage au sol sur la rue du Roi ont été revus **et modifiés / et complètement changés / et améliorés / etc.**.

Comment: Je prends! Merci LPH!